# Missing values replace by med/mean in conti var, by mode in categorical var in pandas dataframe -after grouping the data by a column)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe , where all missing values are np.nan, now I am trying to replace these missing values. The last column of my data is " class" , I need to group the data based on the class, then get mean/median/mode (based on data whether data is categorical/ continuos, normal/ not)  of that group of a column and replace missing values of the group of the coulmn by respective mean/median/mode.

This is the code I have come up with , which I know is an overkill.. 
if I could :

1. group the col of dataframe
2. get median/mode/mean of groups of the cols
3. replace the missing of those groups
4. recombine them back to original df

it would be great.

but currently I landed up , finding replacement values (mean/median/mode) group wise and storing in dict, then seperating the nan tuples and non-nan tuples.. replacing missing values in nan tuples.. and trying to join them back to dataframe (which i donno yet how to do)

```
def fillMissing(df, dataType):
'''
Args:
    df ( 2d array/ Dict):
                         eg : ('attribute1': [12, 24, 25] , 'attribute2': ['good', 'bad'])
    dataTypes (dict): Dictionary of attribute names of df as keys and values 0/1 
                        indicating categorical/continuous variable eg:  ('attribute1':1, 'attribute2': 0)

Returns:
    dataframe wih missing values filled
    writes a file with missing values replaces.    


'''
dataLabels = list(df.columns.values)

# the dictionary to hold the values to put in place of nan
replaceValues = {}

for eachlabel in dataLabels:

    thisSer = df[eachlabel]
    if dataType[eachlabel] == 1:                        # if its a continuous variable 
        _,pval = stats.normaltest(thisSer)
        groupedd = thisSer.groupby(df['class'])

        innerDict ={}
        for name, group in groupedd:
            if(pval < 0.5):
                groupMiddle = group.median()            # get the median of the group
            else:
                groupMiddle = group.mean()              # get mean (if group is normal )
            innerDict[name.strip()] = groupMiddle
        replaceValues[eachlabel] = innerDict

    else:                                               # if the series is continuous
        # freqCount = collections.Counter(thisSer)
        groupedd = thisSer.groupby(df['class'])
        innerDict ={}
        for name, group in groupedd:
            freqC = collections.Counter(group)      
            mostFreq = freqC.most_common(1)             # get the most frequent value of the attribute(grouped by class)
            # newGroup = group.replace(np.nan , mostFreq)
            innerDict[name.strip()] = mostFreq[0][0].strip()
        replaceValues[eachlabel] = innerDict
print replaceValues


# replace the missing values =======================
newfile = open('missingReplaced.csv', 'w')
newdf = df   

mask=False
for col in df.columns: mask = mask | df[col].isnull()

# get the dataframe of tuples that contains nulls
dfnulls = df[mask]
dfnotNulls = df[~mask]


for _, row in dfnulls.iterrows():
    for colname in dataLabels:
        if pd.isnull(row[colname]):
            if row['class'].strip() == '>50K':
                row[colname] = replaceValues[colname]['>50K']
            else:
                row[colname] = replaceValues[colname]['<=50K']
        newfile.write(str(row[colname]) + ",")
    newdf.append(row)
    newfile.write("\n")

# here add newdf to dfnotNulls to get finaldf

return finaldf
```

Comment: It helps if you can provide a small sample dataset and an example of the results you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks @JohnE I am still reading your replay and trying to understand it;  the dataset I am using is http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/  I am working with adult.data file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is mostly in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#transformation), but probably not where you'd be looking if you're asking the question.  See note regarding `mode` at the bottom as it is slightly trickier than `mean` and `median`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'v':[1,2,2,np.nan,3,4,4,np.nan] }, index=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],)

df['v_mean'] = df.groupby(level=0)['v'].transform( lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
df['v_med' ] = df.groupby(level=0)['v'].transform( lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
df['v_mode'] = df.groupby(level=0)['v'].transform( lambda x: x.fillna(x.mode()[0]))

df
    v    v_mean  v_med  v_mode
1   1  1.000000      1       1
1   2  2.000000      2       2
1   2  2.000000      2       2
1 NaN  1.666667      2       2
2   3  3.000000      3       3
2   4  4.000000      4       4
2   4  4.000000      4       4
2 NaN  3.666667      4       4
```

Note that `mode()` may not be unique, unlike `mean` and `median` and pandas returns it as a `Series` for that reason.  To deal with that, I just took the simplest route and added `[0]` in order to extract the first member of the series.